# Git: How to get the commit info of a changeset

Tags: git

I got a changeset after digging around with git blame. Now I want to know more about the changeset. The changes made and comments,etc etc.

What is the git command to get that information?

Looked around, but could not find the answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Maybe [git show](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html)?

It gives you the commit sha, the author, the comment and a complete diff of that commit. If you need you can also specify multiple changeset using [this syntax](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).